# Question about large estimated standard error on exponential distribution

Tags: exponential-distribution, error-propagation, standard-error

I have collected data that is the time between discrete random events and I have a parameter $V$ (voltage) that changes the mean rate of my events. I have used MLE to fit the exponential distribution for all different instances of $V$ (the exponential distribution fit my data neatly in each case) and now want to investigate the relation between $\lambda$ and $V$.

In order to make a nice plot for the relation between $\lambda$ and $V$ I want to show errors on the lambda values I found. I know that for the exponential distribution $\mathrm{Var}[\lambda]=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$ and the estimated standard error $\mathrm{\hat{SE}}\approx\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$. The problem I'm running into is that for low $V$, the lambda value becomes very low and I do not have enough samples to compensate for the high variance of lambda. To give an example for my lowest $V$: $\lambda=2.7\cdot10^{-3},\ \mathrm{Var}[\lambda]=1.4\cdot10^{5}, \ n = 154 \rightarrow \mathrm{\hat{SE}}\approx 30$.

The value of $30$ is huge and it really doesn't make sense to me. This standard error implies that $\lambda$ at this voltage could be larger than for any other voltages I have measured. Intuitively (from my observations during the collection of the data) it would seem the chance of the $\lambda$ at this voltage being higher than those for the high voltages (which do get reasonable estimated standard errors) is astronomically small. Also I think it is impossible for $\lambda$ to be negative.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. Any help or sources would be appreciated!

Comment: *"I know that for the exponential distribution $\mathrm{Var}[\lambda]=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$"* looks strange.   This is not saying the same as $\mathrm{Var}[X]=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$ and  $\mathbb E[X]=\frac{1}{\lambda}$ when $X \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$